# PicklingError: Can't pickle <function mean_root_squared_error_func at 0x7f2efa224e18>: it's not found as __main__.mean_root_squared_error_func

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I have created a custom scorer for the GridSearchCV function:

```
def mean_root_squared_error_func(y_true, y_pred):

    return np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
```

This is how I call the function in my code

```
scoring_grid={'r_squared': "r2",
              'neg_mean_sqr_error': make_scorer(mean_root_squared_error_func, greater_is_better=False)
             }
```

Although after running the GridSearchCV function and trying to pickle the best estimator object I get this error (either with *pickle* or *joblib* functions):

```
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),filename), 'wb') as file:
    joblib.dump(best_model_dictionary[list[0]], file)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <function mean_root_squared_error_func at 0x7f2efa224e18>: it's not found as __main__.mean_root_squared_error_func
```

I read both the pickle documentation and some similar issues on StackOverflow although I did not manage to handle this error.

**Edit 1**
Please note that "neg_root_mean_squared_error" as found in [scikit-learn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) is not supported. It gives back the following error:

```
ValueError: 'neg_root_mean_squared_error' is not a valid scoring value. Use sorted(sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys()) to get valid options.
```

**Edit 2**
After a request to post more code:
A function that return the pipeline_object, parameters_grid, scoring grid to be used by GridSearchCV

```
def regressor_component_initialization(model_name):
    """
    Create the components of:
        - Pipeline object
        - Hyperparameter grid,
        - Scorint metrics

    For the regression model specified
    """

    if model_name=="RandomForest":

        pipeline_object=Pipeline([
                    ('random_forest_regressor', RandomForestRegressor(random_state=123))
                    ])

        pipe_params={
                    'random_forest_regressor__max_depth':[20, None],
                    'random_forest_regressor__max_features':['log2', None]
                    }

        scoring_grid={'r_squared': "r2",
                      'neg_mean_sqr_error': make_scorer(mean_root_squared_error_func, greater_is_better=False)
                    }

    elif model_name=="DecisionTree":

        pipeline_object=Pipeline([
                    ('decision_tree_regressor', DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=123))
                    ])

        pipe_params={
                    'decision_tree_regressor__max_depth':[20, None],
                    'decision_tree_regressor__max_features':['log2', None]
                    }

        scoring_grid={'r_squared': "r2",
                      'neg_mean_sqr_error': make_scorer(mean_root_squared_error_func, greater_is_better=False)
                    }

    return pipeline_object, pipe_params, scoring_grid
```

Next, the function of GridSearchCV:

```
def hyperparameter_tuning(method, model_object, param_grid, cv, scoring, refit, n_iter=1000, split_ratiο=0.2):

    if method=="gridsearch":

        search_object=GridSearchCV(model_object, param_grid=param_grid, cv = cv, verbose=1, n_jobs = -1, scoring=scoring, refit=refit, return_train_score=True)
    return search_object, refit
```

The search_object is then fitted to X_train, y_train

Comment: post the full code. the `PicklingError` error is indeed weird

Comment: @seralouk
I have added some more code, which shows how the gridsearchCV is called

Answer (score 0):

[Dill](https://dill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dill.html) is what I use to serialize basically everything. It should be able to handle weirdly scoped functions and lambda functions.

```
import dill
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),filename), 'wb') as file:
    dill.dump(best_model_dictionary[list[0]], file)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try the dill module and I will notify you about the results.